# Python to call API multiple time and append the part of the response

Tags: python

I am trying to extract data from an API which is working just fine.
The API returns the data and ref link for next API in below format.

```
[
    {
        "_count": 2309444,
        "_links": [
          {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "../this link"
          },
          {
            "rel": "next",
            "href": "../link for next call"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "items": {
          "key1": "value1",
          "key2": "value2",
        }
      },
      {
        "items": {
          "key1": "value3",
          "key2": "value4",
        }
      }
    ]
```

Since we can not put load on API for all the data at once. We are calling that API multiple times using the next reference which is working.
I am trying to call the API in a loop and add all items element into single file. Once the loop is complete I am writing the data into disk.

Now the below code is doing the job but adding extra backlash and even double quotation in the beginning and at the end of file.
Can somebody please suggest where I am going wrong or if there is better way to do it?

```
import requests
import json
import generateToken

#Get the token credential
auth_token = generateToken.generate_token()
headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {auth_token}'}

#Setting up the parameter
limit = 10
pageNav = "true"

#Link to be added in URL
next = f"firstcalllink_limit={limit}&_pageNav={pageNav}&_out=JSON"

#initializing the array to accumalate the data
api_results = []

 
while limit > 0:
    url = f'ActualAPILink/{next}'
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    data =  response.json()
    #Removing the first element so that only data will be appended to final file
    data.pop(0)
    data1 = json.dumps(data)
   
    #creating the url for next count
    next = response.json()[0]['_links'][1]['href']
    next = next[3:]

    #counting the total items so that once limit reach to zero the while loop will end
    limit = len(response.json()) - 1
    api_results.append(data1)
    print(api_results)

#finalling writing the data
with open('mypath/fiename', 'w') as f:
     json.dump(api_results, f)
```